# maximum size of reliable RealtimeMessage not limiting

Tags: android, messaging, multiplayer, google-play-games

When sending reliable multiplayer realtime messages with the google play game services, the documentation tells me:

"The maximum size of a reliable message that you can send is 1400 bytes"

But I am sending messages, way bigger than that and it perfektly works. Why does it work? And should I fear, that at some point, it does not work anymore?

Comment: Have you found out the reason? I have the same problem, earlier I got exception sending message larger than 1400 bytes, now I can send 15000 bytes in one message easily.

Comment: No, I haven't examined it further, but my App is still working fine. Not sure, how it is with messages across platforms.

Answer (score 0):

If you think this is a bug or you want to request more than 1400 bytes as a limit you can write [here](https://code.google.com/p/play-games-platform/).

Otherwise in general; if such a limit is documented, exceeding this limit cannot be guaranteed to work in all cases and/or at all times.